# Unable to get all user's profile info, using Facebook Graph API (C# .net)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

At present i have created an api_key ,api_secret key and generated an access token after creating an facebook app.i have used these access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=" + txtSearch.Text.Trim() + "&type=user&access_token=" + tokenFB
```

in my code to fetch data.... The problem i'm facing is I'm not able to view public data of strangers my code fetches all data of my friends but not others in facebook except their name and profile picture . i want to get data of all facebook users that are have public access.. can sum1 help with what should be my approach? Is there no way of a access token that help me fetch data of all users and not just my friends.

Comment: I think you need to take the UserID, of a person from the search result, and lookup the person using a URL like this: https://graph.facebook.com/USERID

Comment: i have used the userID and i'm already getting the data related to the user but the problem is i'm not getting profile data for all users that is public .actually wanted 2 know if i can filter data that is public is there is setting or way to do that??

Answer (score 0):

All of this depends on the permissions level that the user sets on their profile.  In short you will need to adapt to different settings and hence different information for each user.

You can however request more permissions from Facebook for such a purpose.

Refer to Facebook's documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/).

Comment: I have gone through this document  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: I will explain my concern with an example. Suppose I am User A and wants to access the information of user B who is my friend, I can easily access that and extract that through graph with different permissions for my access token using this documentation. But suppose there is another user C who is not my friend, I am not able to extract even his public info from Graph API even though he has kept those info (for eg Education and work) as everyone(public) in his security settings.are there any means to extract his public info using graph API?

Comment: I have to say this but it works for me when I request the users profile.  I get the basic info that I would expect to be there.

You have to request that particular object from the graph with the userid that you have in hand.

Comment: As a side note you must call up the users' profile, you can't rely on the search function to do the work for you.

Comment: actually i wanted to know if there is any specific way of providing the scope while creating the access token so that i can access the profile data that is public . now i have provided all the scope while creating the access token .is there any particular set of user permissions to be provided in the scope as a parameter??

Comment: @Middletone: CAn you please clarify what are the basic info you are getting when you request the particular users profile. Do you get tht user's public info from the graph API even if this user is not your friend? I can get only the id,name,first_name,last_name,gender,locale and username and not his other info like education and work. I wonder why this data is not available even though he has kept it public. YOur help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please give me the userid that you are asking about?  That will help me figure out the answer for you.

Comment: The user id is for eg "100001227216432". This user is not my friend. I can see his Public info though ( like education and work, location he lives in etc. when I login as a user with this url https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001227216432 .So how should I extract this public info details from graphi api with the help of the access token I have created? I am not finding a way to do tht. All tht I get is id, name, first_name, last_name, link, gender and locale from the graph api.Or is there any other method other than Graph API to extract this data..Please help